# Syncing Outlook calendar with a SharePoint calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar, sync, 2007

I'm trying to sync a SharePoint calendar with an Outlook calendar. SharePoint has the connect to Outlook option and all. I did that, I was also able to copy all the events from Outlook into SharePoint fine. I can add events to the SharePoint calendar through Outlook, but when I add a new event on the Outlook Calendar it doesn't get added to the SharePoint calendar. Meaning the user has to enter it in two places if s/he wants to keep them both up to date. It's important for my users that they don't have to do this. Is there anyway to make SharePoint fetch the events from Outlook automatically?

Thanks 
-V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MS Office are you using?  2003 can support displaying a SharePoint calendar in Outlook, but the sync isn't two way.  With 2007 items created within outlook will be added to the server at the next sync.

Also, which calendar are the items being added to?  When you setup the connection to the SharePoint calendar, it actually defines a second calendar separate from the personal calendar.  If you add items to the personal calendar you will also need to add them to the "shared" calendar.  Where you would add the item, depends on which version of Office you have as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm using 2007 I read somewhere that the sync was 2-way with Outlook 2007 and SP 2007, but it's not working.

If I'm understanding you correctly, then the user would need to add the event to two calendars (both in outlook)?

Comment: If you are using 2007 then the sync is two way as long as you are adding the event to the right calendar.  There is a personal calendar, and another calendar for each site you connect to from outlook.  When you go into the Calendar area there should be a list of calendars available and a heading called "Other Calendars".  Here is a link to the MS Office Online site.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx